# VS2013 ASP.NET 4.0 Usercontrols. Circular file references are not allowed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

Our developers are getting the following 2 errors when building ASP.NET websites in Visual Studio 2013 specifically, which we never got before:

> "The type exists in both ... and ..." and "Circular file references
>   are not allowed.". The 'File' field in the error is always a
>   usercontrol.

A few forum posts suggest adding batch="false" to the compilation section in the web.config, but this does not work, build successfully once, then next build fails again.

I installed VS2013 Update 2. No change. Our projects always build successfully on previous versions of VS, we made not code changes.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2252099/3030434

Comment: possible duplicate of [Circular file references are not allowed. Publish ASP.NET (2.0) Website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251492/circular-file-references-are-not-allowed-publish-asp-net-2-0-website)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions so far (1. using the command line compiler with v parameter or 2. changing the folder structure so usercontrols don't reference other usercontrols in parent folders). I would like to continue using the build function within VS UI and changing the folders didn't work for me.